# Referencing an object in c#

Tags: c#, object, reference

I have a class called node. I want to store each nodes parent within each node like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node parent;
}
```

So say I assign parent to a node:

```
Node n = new Node();
Node n2 = new Node();
n.parent = n2;
```

If I change n2, will the parent variable of n change too?

Comment: Did you mean `n.parent = n2`?

Comment: `Node.parent = n2;` won't compile.

Comment: Does the sun set in the west?

Comment: As one can tell from the answers, your question is not clear. There are two interpretations: "Would `n.parent` change if I do `n2 = something`" and "Would `n.parent` change if I do `n2.parent = ...`" -- which one did you mean to ask?

Comment: might want to get rid of "n1" just call it "n" or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `parent` variable of `n` will not change: once a reference is copied, it gets a life of its own. If you change the `Node` pointed by `n2`, however, `n`'s parent will see that change. For example, if you set `n2.parent = n3`, `n.parent.parent` will change to `n3` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's by reference, `n.parent = n2;`

To be clear, if you change N2 (ie. `N2.prop = newvalue`), when you do `n.Parent.prop`, it'll be the `newvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Node
{
   public string a;
   public Node parent;
}

Node n = new Node();

Node n2 = new Node();
n2.a = "1";
n.parent = n2; 

// n.parent.a is "1" now

n2.a = "2";

// n.parent.a is "2" now
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of variables, parameters, array slots, etc. of class types as holding "object IDs".  A statement like `n1.parent = n2;` says "Find the object identified by the object ID stored in `n1`, which will be of type `Node`; change the `parent` field of that object to contain the object ID stored in `n2`".

Suppose `n1` was initially assigned [Object ID#1] and `n2` was initially assigned [Object ID#2].  The statement `n1.parent = n2` will make the `parent` field of the Object #1 contain [Object ID #2].  If one were to perform a statement like `n2.someProperty = 5` before one stores anything else in `n2`, that statement would modify that property of Object #2.  Since the `parent` field of Object #1 holds [Object ID#2], the statement would also appear to modify `n1.parent.someProperty`.  On the other hand, if one were to store a different object ID into `n2`, that would have no effect on `n1.parent`, which would continue to hold [Object ID #2].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since it is by reference. It will be updated in both n and n2

Comment: OK, thank you. I wasn't sure if it created a new object or stored a reference.

Comment: @Sam no problem! Hope it helps.

Comment: `n2` is a variable.  Changing that variable won't also change all of the variables referencing the same thing. Changing what `n2` references however, would be visible to everything else that references what `n2` references.

Comment: "Changing what n2 reference however, would be visible to everything else that references what n2 references." That's what I am saying "yes" to. I don't think the question is referring to the first part of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you refer to the same object by reference.